# Getting error "Session is closed! Object name: 'ISession' while using Castle Windsor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, castle-windsor

Yes. this is an issue related to how i ask Castle Windsor to resolve my ISession, but i have reread the code like 5 times, and can't still figure out what is wrong with it.

Below is my rather standard NHibernate facility, except for the last 2 components which I have registered:

```
 public class NHibernateFacility : AbstractFacility
    {
        protected override void Init()
        {
            var config = new Configuration().Configure();
            Kernel.Register(
                Component.For<ISessionFactory>()
                    .UsingFactoryMethod((kernel, context) => config.BuildSessionFactory()),
                Component.For<ISession>()
                    .UsingFactoryMethod((kernel, context) => kernel.Resolve<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession())
                    .LifestylePerWebRequest(),
                     Component.For<IStatelessSession>()
                    .UsingFactoryMethod((kernel, context) => kernel.Resolve<ISessionFactory>().OpenStatelessSession())
                    .LifestylePerWebRequest(),
                    Component.For<StatefulSessionWrapper>().LifestylePerWebRequest(),
                    Component.For<StatelessSessionWrapper>().LifestylePerWebRequest()
                );
        }
    }
```

The StatefulSessionWrapper/StatelessSessionWrapper serve as a ... wrapper for ISession/IStateless session like this:

```
public class StatefulSessionWrapper : ISessionWrapper
    {
        public StatefulSessionWrapper(ISession session)
        {
            this.Session = session;
        }

        private readonly ISession Session;

        #region ISessionWrapper Members

        public ITransaction BeginTransaction()
        {
            return Session.BeginTransaction();
        }

        public ITransaction BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
        {
            return Session.BeginTransaction(isolationLevel);
        }

        public ITransaction Transaction { get { return Session.Transaction; } }

        public bool IsConnected
        {
            get { return Session.IsConnected; }
        }

        public bool IsOpen
        {
            get { return Session.IsOpen; }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

This way, I can use a single action filter, which only handles the transaction part of the NHibernate Session:

```
public class NHibernateActionFilter<T> : Castle.MonoRail.Framework.IFilter where T:ISessionWrapper
    {
        private readonly T NHibernateSession;

        public NHibernateActionFilter(T session)
        {
            if (session != null)
                NHibernateSession = session;
            else
                throw new NullReferenceException("Session is null");
        }

        #region IFilter Members

        public bool Perform(ExecuteWhen exec, IEngineContext context, IController controller, IControllerContext controllerContext)
        {
            if (exec == ExecuteWhen.BeforeAction)
            {
                NHibernateSession.BeginTransaction();
                return true;
            }
            if (exec == ExecuteWhen.AfterAction)
            {
                if (NHibernateSession.Transaction == null || !NHibernateSession.Transaction.IsActive)
                    return false;
                if (context.LastException != null)
                {
                    NHibernateSession.Transaction.Rollback();
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    NHibernateSession.Transaction.Commit();
                    return true;
                }

            }
            return false;
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

And use it simply as this:

```
    [Filter(ExecuteWhen.Always, typeof(NHibernateActionFilter<StatefulSessionWrapper>), ExecutionOrder = 1)]
    [Filter(ExecuteWhen.BeforeAction, typeof(AuthenticationFilter), ExecutionOrder = 2)]
    [Layout("Default"), Rescue("Default")]
    public abstract class NHibernateController : SmartDispatcherController
    {
        public NHibernateController(ISession session)
        {
            this.NHibernateSession = session;
        }

        protected readonly ISession NHibernateSession;
        ..................
```

The only problem?

> This is the rescue page. See the exception details below
>
> ObjectDisposedException
>
> Message: Session is closed! Object name: 'ISession'.
>
> StackTrace:    at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.ErrorIfClosed()
>   in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Impl\AbstractSessionImpl.cs:line
>   207    at
>   NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CheckAndUpdateSessionStatus() in
>   p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Impl\AbstractSessionImpl.cs:line 199
>   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.BeginTransaction() in
>   p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Impl\SessionImpl.cs:line 1456    at
>   ADAutoTotal.Monorail.StatefulSessionWrapper.BeginTransaction() in
>   C:\Dropbox\Projects\ADAutoTotal\ADAutoTotal.Monorail\StatefulSessionWrapper.cs:line
>   23    at
>   ADAutoTotal.Monorail.NHibernateActionFilter`1.Perform(ExecuteWhen
>   exec, IEngineContext context, IController controller,
>   IControllerContext controllerContext) in
>   C:\Dropbox\Projects\ADAutoTotal\ADAutoTotal.Monorail\NHibernateActionFilter.cs:line
>   31    at
>   Castle.MonoRail.Framework.Controller.ProcessFilter(ExecuteWhen when,
>   FilterDescriptor desc) in
>   C:\Dropbox\Projects\Monorail\castleproject-MonoRail-98c93ac\castleproject-MonoRail-98c93ac\MR2\src\Castle.MonoRail.Framework\Controller.cs:line 2099    at
>   Castle.MonoRail.Framework.Controller.ProcessFilters(IExecutableAction
>   action, ExecuteWhen when) in
>   C:\Dropbox\Projects\Monorail\castleproject-MonoRail-98c93ac\castleproject-MonoRail-98c93ac\MR2\src\Castle.MonoRail.Framework\Controller.cs:line 2054    at
>   Castle.MonoRail.Framework.Controller.RunBeforeActionFilters(IExecutableAction
>   action, Boolean& cancel) in
>   C:\Dropbox\Projects\Monorail\castleproject-MonoRail-98c93ac\castleproject-MonoRail-98c93ac\MR2\src\Castle.MonoRail.Framework\Controller.cs:line 1953    at
>   Castle.MonoRail.Framework.Controller.RunActionAndRenderView() in
>   C:\Dropbox\Projects\Monorail\castleproject-MonoRail-98c93ac\castleproject-MonoRail-98c93ac\MR2\src\Castle.MonoRail.Framework\Controller.cs:line 1622

So, it's obvious that the NHibernateActionFilter gets a closed session. But according to me, it shouldn't. Halp.

Comment: Using an Action filter for Session Management is not the best way to go about doing things.

Comment: I only create a session when I need to use it and wrap it in a transaction. I use Windsor for the disposing of my SessionManager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turns out that i forgot to add to my action filter their proper lifestyles, therefore letting Windsor making them singleton...

Comment: I had set an instant to ThreadScope() in Ninject. So the next thread was not finding the session object and erroring out. Seeing the word Singleton in @Cosmo it struck me.